# JavaScript: Merge only difference/changes of 2 array of objects into new array of objects

Tags: javascript

I need some help. How can I merge only difference/changes of 2 array of objects into new array of objects?

Use Case 1:

```
const oldMeta = [
  { fieldName: "item", fieldLabel: "Item" }, 
  { fieldName: "location", fieldLabel: "Location", displayLabel: "Place" }, 
  { fieldName: "createdDate", fieldLabel: "Created Date", displayLabel: "C Date" }, 
  { fieldName: "owner", fieldLabel: "Owner" }, 
  { fieldName: "status", fieldLabel: "Status" },
];

const newMeta = [
  { fieldName: "item", fieldLabel: "Item" }, 
  { fieldName: "location", fieldLabel: "Location" },
  { fieldName: "city", fieldLabel: "City" }, 
  { fieldName: "createdDate", fieldLabel: "Creation Date" }, 
  { fieldName: "ownerName", fieldLabel: "Owner" }, 
  { fieldName: "severity", fieldLabel: "Severity" },
  { fieldName: "status", fieldLabel: "Status" },
];
```

I want the output to be:

```
[
  { fieldName: "item", fieldLabel: "Item" }, 
  { fieldName: "location", fieldLabel: "Location", displayLabel: "Place" }, 
  { fieldName: "city", fieldLabel: "City" }, 
  { fieldName: "createdDate", fieldLabel: "Creation Date", displayLabel: "C Date" }, 
  { fieldName: "ownerName", fieldLabel: "Owner" }, 
  { fieldName: "severity", fieldLabel: "Severity" },
  { fieldName: "status", fieldLabel: "Status" },
]
```

Use Case 2:

```
const oldMeta = [
  { fieldName: "item", fieldLabel: "Item" }, 
  { fieldName: "location", fieldLabel: "Location", displayLabel: "Place" },
  { fieldName: "city", fieldLabel: "City" }, 
  { fieldName: "createdDate", fieldLabel: "Created Date", displayLabel: "C Date" }, 
  { fieldName: "ownerName", fieldLabel: "Owner" }, 
  { fieldName: "severity", fieldLabel: "Severity" },
  { fieldName: "status", fieldLabel: "Status" },
]; 

const newMeta = [
  { fieldName: "item", fieldLabel: "Item" }, 
  { fieldName: "location", fieldLabel: "Location" }, 
  { fieldName: "createdDate", fieldLabel: "Creation Date" }, 
  { fieldName: "owner", fieldLabel: "Owner" }, 
  { fieldName: "status", fieldLabel: "Status" },
];
```

I want the output to be:

```
[
  { fieldName: "item", fieldLabel: "Item" }, 
  { fieldName: "location", fieldLabel: "Location", displayLabel: "Place" },
  { fieldName: "createdDate", fieldLabel: "Creation Date", displayLabel: "C Date" }, 
  { fieldName: "owner", fieldLabel: "Owner" }, 
  { fieldName: "status", fieldLabel: "Status" },
]
```

Following points need to be considered:

- If `old` contains `fieldName`s that are not there in `new`, they should not appear in resulting output.
- If `new` contains new `fieldName`s, they should appear in resulting output.
- If `new` contains changes in properties, the resulting output should contain both, the changed properties and existing properties.

What is the most efficient way to handle both use cases?

Have created a fiddle of what I have tried so far:

```js
const fillObject = (from, to) => {
    for (var key in from) {
        if (from.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (Object.prototype.toString.call(from[key]) === '[object Object]') {
                if (!to.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    to[key] = {};
                }
                fillObject(from[key], to[key]);
            }
            else if (!to.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                to[key] = from[key];
            }
        }
    }
}

// Use case 1
const oldMeta1 = [
  { fieldName: "item", fieldLabel: "Item" }, 
  { fieldName: "location", fieldLabel: "Location", displayLabel: "Place" }, 
  { fieldName: "createdDate", fieldLabel: "Created Date", displayLabel: "C Date" }, 
  { fieldName: "owner", fieldLabel: "Owner" }, 
  { fieldName: "status", fieldLabel: "Status" },
];

const newMeta1 = [
  { fieldName: "item", fieldLabel: "Item" }, 
  { fieldName: "location", fieldLabel: "Location" },
  { fieldName: "city", fieldLabel: "City" }, 
  { fieldName: "createdDate", fieldLabel: "Creation Date" }, 
  { fieldName: "ownerName", fieldLabel: "Owner" }, 
  { fieldName: "severity", fieldLabel: "Severity" },
  { fieldName: "status", fieldLabel: "Status" },
];

let finalMeta1 = [...newMeta1];

finalMeta1.forEach((newMetaData) => {
    const oldMetaData = oldMeta1.find((oldMetaData) => newMetaData.fieldName === oldMetaData.fieldName);
  if (oldMetaData) {
    fillObject(oldMetaData, newMetaData)
  }
});

console.log(finalMeta1);

// Use case 2
const oldMeta2 = [
  { fieldName: "item", fieldLabel: "Item" }, 
  { fieldName: "location", fieldLabel: "Location", displayLabel: "Place" },
  { fieldName: "city", fieldLabel: "City" }, 
  { fieldName: "createdDate", fieldLabel: "Created Date", displayLabel: "C Date" }, 
  { fieldName: "ownerName", fieldLabel: "Owner" }, 
  { fieldName: "severity", fieldLabel: "Severity" },
  { fieldName: "status", fieldLabel: "Status" },
];

const newMeta2 = [
  { fieldName: "item", fieldLabel: "Item" }, 
  { fieldName: "location", fieldLabel: "Location" }, 
  { fieldName: "createdDate", fieldLabel: "Creation Date" }, 
  { fieldName: "owner", fieldLabel: "Owner" }, 
  { fieldName: "status", fieldLabel: "Status" },
];

let finalMeta2 = [...newMeta2];

finalMeta2.forEach((newMetaData) => {
    const oldMetaData = oldMeta2.find((oldMetaData) => newMetaData.fieldName === oldMetaData.fieldName);
  if (oldMetaData) {
    fillObject(oldMetaData, newMetaData)
  }
});

console.log(finalMeta2);
```

Comment: _"Don't ask about...

    Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"_ [tour]

Comment: @jabaa I am confused as to how to go about this, hence I am asking.

Comment: _"Asking a question on Stack Overflow should be the last step in your process for finding an answer"_ [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please show your work. What have you tried so far? Show your approaches. Describe why they didn't work.

Comment: @jabaa Added a JSFiddle of what I've been trying so far.

Comment: What's wrong with your code? It looks like it's already working

Comment: @jabaa I wanted to know if there was a more efficient way to do this as I am worried about performance.

Comment: Yes, there is a more efficient way. You can avoid the linear search with `find` using a map with instant access or binary search. You can see an alternative in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can improve readability and performance using Lodash:

```js
// Use case 1
const oldMeta1 = [
  { fieldName: "item", fieldLabel: "Item" }, 
  { fieldName: "location", fieldLabel: "Location", displayLabel: "Place" }, 
  { fieldName: "createdDate", fieldLabel: "Created Date", displayLabel: "C Date" }, 
  { fieldName: "owner", fieldLabel: "Owner" }, 
  { fieldName: "status", fieldLabel: "Status" },
];

const newMeta1 = [
  { fieldName: "item", fieldLabel: "Item" }, 
  { fieldName: "location", fieldLabel: "Location" },
  { fieldName: "city", fieldLabel: "City" }, 
  { fieldName: "createdDate", fieldLabel: "Creation Date" }, 
  { fieldName: "ownerName", fieldLabel: "Owner" }, 
  { fieldName: "severity", fieldLabel: "Severity" },
  { fieldName: "status", fieldLabel: "Status" },
];

// Use case 2
const oldMeta2 = [
  { fieldName: "item", fieldLabel: "Item" }, 
  { fieldName: "location", fieldLabel: "Location", displayLabel: "Place" },
  { fieldName: "city", fieldLabel: "City" }, 
  { fieldName: "createdDate", fieldLabel: "Created Date", displayLabel: "C Date" }, 
  { fieldName: "ownerName", fieldLabel: "Owner" }, 
  { fieldName: "severity", fieldLabel: "Severity" },
  { fieldName: "status", fieldLabel: "Status" },
];

const newMeta2 = [
  { fieldName: "item", fieldLabel: "Item" }, 
  { fieldName: "location", fieldLabel: "Location" }, 
  { fieldName: "createdDate", fieldLabel: "Creation Date" }, 
  { fieldName: "owner", fieldLabel: "Owner" }, 
  { fieldName: "status", fieldLabel: "Status" },
];

function merge(oldMeta, newMeta) {
  const oldMetaMap = _.keyBy(oldMeta, el => el.fieldName);

  return newMeta.map(el => {
    if (el.fieldName in oldMetaMap) {
      return {..._.cloneDeep(oldMetaMap[el.fieldName]), ..._.cloneDeep(el)};
    }
    return _.cloneDeep(el);
  });
}
console.log(merge(oldMeta1, newMeta1));
console.log(merge(oldMeta2, newMeta2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @jabba. This does enhance readability and also reduce the amount of steps required to achieve what I want to do.